# Fork and drop privileges with Java

Tags: java, unix, process, permissions, fork

I'm writing a server program in Java that will allow users to submit jobs using DRMAA. Although the main server process runs as `root`, all it does is authenticate the user, then start another Java program which runs as that user and actually does the work in order to comply with the principle of minimising privileges. Initially, I was doing this with `Runtime.exec()` and `sudo` (example below) which works fine until the process is dæmonised, at which point `sudo` gets upset because it doesn't have a terminal.

```
String[] command = {"sudo", "-i", "-u", username, java, theOtherJavaProgram};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, getHomeDirectory(username));
```

What's the best way to do this fork and drop privileges pattern in Java when running as a daemon? Is there a way? Am I going to have to break out the C and learn how to create JVMs with JNI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `su(1)` instead of `sudo(8)`. `su(1)` is much less involved, and probably won't want the terminal itself. (Of course, if your PAM configuration requires terminal input for `su(1)`, then this might not work well either.)

Answer (score 6):

It's probably easier to just use JNI to drop privileges.

Here's one I knocked up earlier:

`UID.java`

```
public class UID {

    public static native int setuid(int uid);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("uid");
    }
}
```

`unix_uid.c`

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "UID.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_UID_setuid(JNIEnv * jnienv, jclass j, jint uid)
{
    return((jint)setuid((uid_t)uid));
}
```

`UID.h` is machine generated from `UID.class` using `javah`.

Comment: this code will produce errors at some point since `uid_t` is unsigned on some systems and `jint` is signed. Casting is very bad in general - you have a design flaw if all of your JNI libraries use casting.

Answer (score 0):

If you *only* want to start a non-`root` process as `root`, then `su` will be sufficient. It will not ask for a password when going *from* `root` to another user, so it should not need a terminal.