# Is there a Linux Service

Tags: java, linux

I am writing a program in java for an embedded linux platform.  One of the OS features I need has to run as root to get access.  The platform I am using is the BeagleBone Black and I want to control the Gpio pins using a memory map.  I have access to the memory map and can switch the pins on and off at a very fast rate.  The problem is, I don't want my program to have to run as super user, at least it doesn't seem right to implement it that way.

Is there a standard technology in linux that will run as root and let a user program make calls to it?

I know there must be, I just don't know what it is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that you must have a look at *kernel modules*.

Comment: What's your outer problem? Using a memory map just seems like a way to make things harder for no reason.

Comment: My program is written in java.  I could switch the pins using file read and write but it is really slow.  If there is not a better way to do it, I will use file io, it just seems limiting.

Comment: What part of this problem requires running the process as root? I can't see any.

Comment: Access to the memory map gpio pins.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to *drop privileges*. Instead of having any process running as root for the duration, this allows a process to start as root, open resources, and then change to a different, unprivileged user. You'll still need to start the program as root, which can be done with a setuid script so that you don't need the user to be root already to run it. (This is done with other programs, like `sudo`.)

You can open the file as root, and then change the uid of the program to an unprivileged user (presumably the user that started the program). Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5140246/640734) to see how to drop privileges in Java using JNI, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357855/640734) for more information about a robust way to drop privileges in general.